# Do kinematic descriptions define forces?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics

If we have a collection of rigid bodies linked throughout joints where each joint follows a known curve in 3d space, can we reverse engineer the forces used to accelerate the bodies to follow the given path?

Comment: That's how Newton determined gravity follows an inverse square law.

Comment: Not if no time information is given. For example a rigid pendulum will draw a circle, but the centripetal force is unknown unless its speed is given.

Comment: Suppose we also know time, then what? Basically I am curious if the feed-forward forces are uniquely defined by the trajectory the rigid body takes and how one might compute them.

Answer (score 3):

If you by "reverse engineer" mean figuring out the forces and interactions in the past that lead to the current position/configuration, **then theoretically yes**. As long as we know all necessary parameters.

In the classical paradigm, every interaction is fully deterministic and thus fully backtraceable if all necessary information is given. But depending on your number of involved objects, you might soon reach a so-called chaotic system where predictions and thus also backtracing are practically impossible.

Look up the celestial **$n$-body problem** or the **double pendulum** for good simple examples of mechanical initially simple-looking systems that quickly show chaotic behaviour and become unrealistic to fully analyse. The double-pendulum motion is illustrated here (in 2D) (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_pendulum)):

[image]

Comment: So I understand that analysis gets hard if you try to predict longterm behavior of dynamical systems from the ODEs, but this doesn't really answer my question on how one computes the forces if you know how the system evolves(basically exactly).

Comment: by evolves, I mean kinematically evolves I should say,

Comment: @FourierFlux Yes, longerm predictions into the future or back into the past quickly get very, very hard with many bodies involved. The reason for this is specifically that such systems easily become hyper sensitive to the chosen initial conditions of the ODE.

Comment: @FourierFlux Theoretically, if you know all necessary kinematic properties at any moment during the path, and you are looking for the forces that have influenced this path, then you basically only have to consider the acceleration (assuming the object isn't deformed or fractured (losing mass) along the way). This is basically just Newton's 2nd law. If you only have start and end acceleration, then you must be able to assume that any acting forces have been constant throughout. This is a general description in lack of a more specific scenario - can you maybe describe your exact task?

Answer (score 1):

If the trajectories of each joint are known, and between joints there are rigid bodies, then the aceleration of all points are known.

For any small element inside one of that bodies, it is valid for the $x$ direction:

$(\sigma_{xx}(x+\delta x) - \sigma_{xx}(x)) \delta y \delta z + (\sigma_{yx}(y+\delta y) - \sigma_{yx}(y)) \delta x \delta z + (\sigma_{zx}(z+\delta z) - \sigma_{zx}(z)) \delta x \delta y = \delta m a_x$

Dividing by the volume $\delta x \delta y \delta z$ and taking the limit when $\delta$'s go to zero:

$$\frac{\partial \sigma_{xx}} {\partial x}  + \frac{\partial \sigma_{yx}} {\partial y}  + \frac{\partial \sigma_{zx}} {\partial z}  = \mu a_x$$

Same procedure for $a_y$ and $a_z$. At first it seems there are $6$ unknowns (not nine because $\sigma_{ij} = \sigma_{ji})$. But not only the accelerations are known but also the velocities and positions. In this case, the stresses $\sigma_{ij}$ can be expressed as a function of the principal stresses $\sigma_{I},\sigma_{II}, \sigma_{III}$ in the objects. So, the stress tensor is determined for each point at any time.

I assume that the joints are frictionless and allow free rotation of the connected parts. It is based on that assumption that we can say that there are only normal stresses in the direction between 2 joints.